# Get Exception after install NopCommerce Bundled Discounts plugin

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nopcommerce

I hosted my NopCommerce project to server and after that I decided to install "Bundled Discounts plugin" it is installed successfully, but when I click on configure button it get me this exception:

```
The controller for path '/Admin/Widget/ConfigureWidget' was not 
    found or does not implement IController.
```

The configure works fine for all other plugins except this one 
How can Ii get rid of this exception?

Do i need to recompile?  If yes, how can I do that on server?

Comment: Where you get that exception? on log or directly on screen?